# Easeljs (createjs) unable to bind two event listener

Tags: javascript, oop, createjs, easeljs

I'm trying to create a particle that moves by mouse position. So, I have created a class that creates a particle. And I'm able to add an event listener by calling "handleMouseEvent()"

Please see this fiddle :

http://bit.ly/1UczZvF

Expected result is both two particle that moves by mouse actions. But result is; only one particle is moving, the first ones event listener is overridden.

At the most bottom of the code you will see two create procedure. When I call two create procedure the second one overrides the first ones event listener.

Can you please advice me why this code doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your fiddle to use the `scope` parameter of the `on()` method, which is much cleaner. I *think* it works now (not exactly sure what you were going for), but it affects both particles.

```
particleClass.prototype.handleMouseEvent=function(){
    stage.on("stagemousemove",function(){
        console.log(this.currentX);
        this.setXYByMousePosition(stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY);
    }, this);
    return this;
};
```

Here is the updated version:
https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/xLgwfj99/6/

Comment: Thanks for your response. You have saved my time. I'm learning easel from your examples here is one of them :)  http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/17xec9y5/9/

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!